# Django Bootstrap | Imagenes mediante for de django muestran sólo la primera imagen en carrousel bootstrap

Tags: html5, django

Al crear un carrousel con Bootstrap, se muestra la primera imagen, pero no las siguiente.
No estoy seguro si puede ser algo de de la clase "active". Parece que en bootstrap a la primera de las imágenes hay que indicarle clase active y el resto no. Pero al querer mostrar todos las imágenes mediante FOR de Django, todas tienen "active".

¿Dónde está el error?

Archivo template.html

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      
      {% for img in station.image_station.all %}
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ img.image_imageStation.url }}" alt="">
      </div>  
      {% endfor %}
      
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: me parece que solo un elemento a la vez debe tener la clase active, prueba sin el for poniendo 3 imagenes directamente y ponle a las tres como active a ver si funciona.

Comment: Con un active: funciona ; Con todos active : no funciona ; Con ningún active no funciona. El problema es que necesito usar for ya que a veces hay una imagen, otras veces varias o ninguna. Funciona de forma dinámica desde la base de datos.

Comment: pues entonces efectivamente es el active, te recomiendo leer esto https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/django-1-0/capitulo-4/etiquetas-basicas-de-plantillas-y-filtros especificamente la sección 4.3.1.2, el ciclo for tiene una propiedad para saber si se hizo la primera iteración y según eso añades la clase.

Comment: Así es, en un grupo de facebook me han indicado eso de forloop. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Forloop permite saber si es el primer loop o no.
Por eso se puede mostrar la clase active solo en el primer for:

```
  {% for img in station.image_station.all %}
  <div class="carousel-item
    {% if forloop.first %}
      active
    {% endif %}
  ">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ img.image_imageStation.url }}" alt="">
  </div>  
  {% endfor %}
```